# Processing a collection of objects, one at a time, with an asynchronous method.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I currently use setInterval and a wait flag to process this collection. Is there a cleaner way?

```
var wait = false;
var processInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if(!wait){
        var currentVideo = videos.shift();

        if(currentVideo){
            wait = true;

            validateSongById(currentVideo.videoId, function(result){
                wait = false;
                if(result){
                    clearInterval(processInterval);
                    callback(currentVideo);
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically there, I would say. If the `validateSongById` function works as  expected, it'll call its callback when it's done, and you then do it again for the next video.

```
function processVideos(videos, callback) {
    var results = [], i = 0;
    function processNext() {
        if(i < videos.length) {
            validateSongById(videos[i].videoId, function (result) {
                results.push(result);
                i++;
                processNext();
            });
        } else {
            callback(results); // when called, all the videos have been processed
        }
    }
    processNext(); // start the processing
}
```

With this, you call `processVideos` with the videos array and a callback. The callback is called with a new array of all the results.

Alternatively, you can attach the result to the `video`-object directly, so the video and the result are tied together:

```
function processVideos(videos, callback) {
    var i = 0;
    function processNext() {
        if(i < videos.length) {
            validateSongById(videos[i].videoId, function (result) {
                videos[i].result = result;
                i++;
                processNext();
            });
        } else {
            callback(); // when called, all the videos have been processed
        }
    }
    processNext(); // start the processing
}
```